# Production, Staging, Dev websites and git repos on same server: how to setup GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, github, agile

I've read a number of posts that seem to get me close but not all the way to what I'd like. I have one server. On it, I have 3 websites: www.domain.com, staging.domain.com, and dev.domain.com. I also develop on local.domain.com and also use GitHub as my central repo.

I'd like to keep my git repositories out of my web roots. I'm open to how to do this. What I'm trying is:

```
/home/user/git/production.git 
/home/user/git/staging.git
/home/user/git/development.git
```

I know how to do this if there's only 1 site and repo by setting GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE (I export the paths in .bash_profile).

It seems I can set the working tree within each repository's `config`, like:

```
[core]
    bare = false
    worktree = /home/user/domains/www.domain.com/public_html
```

**But how do I set `GIT_DIR`?**

So if I'm in /home/user/domains/**www**.domain.com/public_html and do a `git status`, etc., it's referring to the **production** git repo.  And if I'm in /home/user/domains/**staging**.domain.com/public_html, it is tied to **staging**.git.

Comment: i've solved the dev/staging/production issue using git in this manner... My master brnach is the head of my dev branch (I do dev locally...). I then make a branch that reflects the changes to the configuration to make it staging, I then create another branch off of the staging branch to make the config changes for production. Everytime I'm ready to deploy, i rebase my staging and production branches (after tagging them with a version for history reasons) onto my dev branch... This keeps everything nice and neat and in one git tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than setting `$GIT_DIR` you could use gitlink files.  To do this simply go into the root of each working tree and run:

```
echo "gitdir: /home/user/git/production.git" > .git
```

This would result in a `.git` file in your web root, but the only thing that would leak if somebody accessed that would be the path to the repository.  This would avoid needing to play games with setting the `$GIT_DIR` variable based on which directory you're in.

Comment: Nifty! Never seen that before. Feature description on the [gitrepository-layout man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html).

Comment: Wow, that was a simple, and works like a charm! I would like to type up how to set up this development / git environment step by step so others can benefit from all the tips I found here and elsewhere. Can anyone suggest a good place to document this, maybe wiki style. E.g., is Stack Overflow, GitHub, Gist, or something like that a good place where others can find it and maybe even contribute?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

When in your `/home/user/git/production.git` it should detect the working directory as `/home/user/domains/www.domain.com/public.html` and push/pull/checkout should work fine there. Unfortunately, git is not psychic--from a random directory without a `.git` folder git doesn't even know where to look for a configuration file (without [a "gitdir" file](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html), as I just learned about from the other answer).

You can always pass in `git --git-dir=~git/production.git checkout ...` and so forth, but I bet you're looking for an automated solution.

Maybe try wrapping git in a shell script? What if you put this as `~/bin/autogit`:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=$(pwd)
if (fgrep -q domains/www.domain.com <<< "$DIR"); then
  git --git-dir=/home/user/git/production.git $@
elif (fgrep -q domains/staging.domain.com <<< "$DIR"); then
  git --git-dir=/home/user/git/staging.git $@
elif (fgrep -q domains/local.domain.com <<< "$DIR"); then
  git --git-dir=/home/user/git/development.git $@
fi
echo "Autogit failed from directory $DIR."
exit 1
```

(Side note: Why do you have three repos? I've found it more common to have one repo with three different branch names, and a script that checks out each branch to its appropriate directory.)

Comment: There would need to be a repo for each working tree since each would need a different `HEAD`.  There is the `contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir` script from `git.git` which can get around that somewhat, but it can be a bit dangerous if not used carefully.